# Can a deleted application be restored from Google cloud application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have accidentally deleted my application hosted in Google cloud app engine. IS there any way to restore it?

Comment: Did you even try finding out ?

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project

Comment: @AlanB the link you provided is about the restoration of the project itself. The question is specifically about the application deleted from GAE.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? What is the series of steps you were doing?
An app engine app can only be disabled. If you deleted your project then the comment of Alan should suffice.

Comment: Hi, as Antonio mentioned App Engine applications can be disabled as is explained here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/cleaning-up#disabling_your_application, maybe you are talking about App Engine services (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuration-files#examples) Also would be useful if you can share what kind of App Engine are you using(flexible or standard) in order to understand better your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for asking your question on the Google App Engine topic.

To answer your question, no, it can't be restored if the Google App Engine service or the version you expect is deleted already.

The hierarchy is as follows - Account > Project > GAE Service > Versions

Whenever you deploy the app to a specific service, an additional new version is created for the service and the traffic is routed to that version. The old version is not deleted by default. In case you have not deleted it, you can select it under https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions page and re-route traffic to it. In case you have deleted the old version manually, then poof - it's permanantly gone.

**Note** - If you're referring that you have deleted the GCP project itself, then you should be able to restore it within 30 days. Find the support documentation here - https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project